# Modx Revolution Custom Page Title

Tags: php, modx, modx-revolution

I am attempting to build a snippet which will display a custom page title for my portfolio.  The issue that I am having is my code only returns the 'else', yet when I run the query in MySql I am getting the `name`.

What am I doing wrong?

```
<?php
// Show All Errors
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', '1');

$getID = $modx->quote($getID);

$ret = '';
$qry = "SELECT `name` FROM `modx_gallery_items` WHERE REPLACE(LOWER(`name`), ' ', '-') = $getID;";

$result = $modx->query($qry);
if ($result) {
    $row = $result->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    if($row){
        $ret = 'o7th Web Design &raquo; Portfolio &raquo; ' . $row['name'];
    }else{ //It's showing this one on the page, yet the same query in MySQL returns `name`
        $ret = 'o7th Web Design &raquo; Portfolio &raquo; Our Portfolio' . $qry;
    }
    unset($row);        
}else{
    $ret = 'o7th Web Design &raquo; Portfolio &raquo; Our Portfolio' . $qry;
}

// Return everything
echo $ret;
?>
```

Comment: Have you `var_dump($result)` ? If its returning 0 or FALSE, then your getting the last else, which is a duplicate of the else you commented.

Comment: This seems like a lot of code for a page title, Can you describe more specifically the result you are looking for?

Comment: @phpisuber01 - var_dump($row) is returning (bool)False.  I have not done $result as of yet, but I assume that it will be something since it gets past that point.  I'll let you know in a few

Comment: @mmcglynn this is not a typical page title.   I have built a custom 'gallery' for my portfolio, so when you are on my list page and click a link to an item, it goes to a bogus "page", which pulls the items details.  On this "page" I want to display the title as formatted in the code above

Comment: @phpisuber01 - var_dump($result) shows `object(PDOStatement)#26 (1) {
  ["queryString"]=>
  string(109) "SELECT `name` FROM `modx_gallery_items` WHERE REPLACE(LOWER(`name`), ' ', '-') = 'accu-time-systems';"
}`

Comment: yes, the query is correct, please see my question.   the query produced returns the correct results when run in phpMyAdmin against the datbase

Comment: what's really making me scratch my head, the same method is used to pull the content of the "page", in fact the only difference is there are 2 more fields

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found the issue.

`$row = $result->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);`

Needs to change to:

`$row = $result->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);`

And then I can either loop the returned array, or return the item by index: `$row[0]['name']`

Answer (score 0):

You absolutely do not know how to make query in modx revolution. Please read http://bobsguides.com/revolution-objects.html . The correct example of this code looks like this -

```
// add class to work with gallery extra
$gallery = $modx->getService('gallery','Gallery',$modx->getOption('gallery.core_path',null,$modx->getOption('core_path').'components/gallery/').'model/gallery/',$scriptProperties);
if (!($gallery instanceof Gallery)) return '';

// get id of album
$getID = (int) $modx->getOption('getID',$scriptProperties,false);
if (empty($getID)) return 'no id';

// make query
$c = $modx->newQuery('galAlbum')
$c->where(array(
    'id' => $getID,
));
$item = $modx->getObject('galAlbum',$c);

// get result
if (!empty($item)) {
    $output = 'o7th Web Design &raquo; Portfolio &raquo; ' . $item->get('name');
}
else {
    $output = 'o7th Web Design &raquo; Portfolio &raquo; Our Portfolio' . ' empty';
}

return $output;
```

Comment: "You absolutely do not know how to make query in modx revolution."  Actually I do thank you, and the code I posted is much less overhead than what you have posted

Comment: on top of that, my gallery is not a modx object, it is simply a table in the modx database for my use

Comment: `the code I posted is much less overhead than what you have posted ` - code that you wrote does not use a huge opportunity that provides caching xpdo, so your code will spend more resources

Comment: http://rtfm.modx.com/display/revolution20/Using+Custom+Database+Tables+in+your+3rd+Party+Components - this is how to work with your custom tables. Just use the native capabilities offered modx revolution.

Comment: you're right.  If I wanted to spend the time to incorporate a simple table into Modx, that is how it should be done, however, since I do not have the time, nor do I need to take the time to do that, I built a simple table to store data and display the values it contains (took 2 minutes), and I am doing it this way.  Please get back on topic

Comment: If you're actually using the Gallery extra then I would go with what Vasis posted as the 'package' already exists. But that's not to say that it's wrong to use plain PDO methods, as xPDO is basically an extension of this. Depending on available time and budget it's sometimes necessary to choose between the 'recommended' way or a faster way, but they both achieve the same result. Keep it friendly guys...

Comment: Also, while it's true that Vasis' method benefits from built-in caching, if you call the snippet cached then after the first load there will be no difference in performance at all.

Comment: #1 I'm not using the Gallery extra (as I've already stated), #2 I do not need nor want any caching with this

Answer (score -1):

is this the issue?

```
$qry = "SELECT `name` FROM `modx_gallery_items` WHERE REPLACE(LOWER(`name`), ' ', '-') = $getID;";
```

should be:

```
$qry = "SELECT `name` FROM `modx_gallery_items` WHERE REPLACE(LOWER(`name`), ' ', '-') = ".$getID.";";
```

looks like your query would be searching for '$getID' rather than it's actual value

Comment: php is a templated scripting language.  using the "" makes it literal (I think that's what it's called), meaning the query is correct

Comment: no dude - you are wrong, your php variable is not getting interpreted. Look again and check your syntax.

Comment: no dude, actually, I'm not wrong, and it is getting interpreted.  If you read the 5th comment under the question you'll see that it does exactly what I wanted it to do and returning me the correct query at the correct time.

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.double

Comment: Thank you for proving my point...  and I quote `The most important feature of double-quoted strings is the fact that variable names will be expanded. See string parsing for details.`